# content of char pointer not getting printed

Tags: c

I'm trying to print the content of my char pointer after it receives user input. However, nothing gets printed when I run the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *getUserInput(){

char a[100];      
scanf("%s",a);     
return a;     
}

int main(){

char *ans;
ans = getUserInput();

printf("%s\n",ans);
return 0;
}
```

moreover I tried with hello and as you can see I tried to print the first character of ans and it does contain h, so the error most likely come from the print statement.

Comment: The array `a` in the `getUserInput` function is *local* inside that function. When the function returns, the life-time of all local variables ends, and the pointer you return will become immediately invalid. I recommend you pass a pointer to the buffer as an argument instead (or just use `scanf` directly instead).

Comment: By the way, you might want to [edit] your question to fix the double copy-paste of your [mcve]. We also can't see any output or what it prints, since you don't show it. Also please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: you got a main inside a main?

Comment: Indent the code properly while you're at it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a pointer to a local variable, causing undefined behaviour. To correct it, you need to do

```
char *a;
a=malloc(100);
```

instead of

```
char a[100];
```

because in the later case, `a` gets destroyed beyond the function scope, returning a pointer that points to garbage (an unallocated memory).

Answer (score 0):

When the function execution ends all the memory related to local variable are freed.
you can write your code like this.
And to print the first character of the array you have to value at address operator(*).

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<malloc.h>

char * getUserInput() {
  char * a;
  a = (char * ) malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
  scanf("%s", a);
  return a;
}

int main() {
    char * ans;
    ans = getUserInput();
    printf("%s\n", ans);
    printf("%c\n", * ans);
    return 0;
    `
}
```